# Excluding form elements on keypress

Tags: jquery, forms, keypress

I have a keypress assigned to a div, for example pressing A will show the div, press again to hide, problem is this also happens in form elements, have looked at other questions and answers but none worked for me.

I'm using:

```
$(document).keypress(function(ev) {
if (ev.which === 65 || ev.which === 97) { // 'A' or 'a'
     $('#mainMenu').toggle();
}
});
```

How can I exclude textfields from this?

Answer (score 4):

check the ev.target

something like:

```
if ($(ev.target).is(":input")) {
    return;
}
```